# Delphi: suggests, ideas in a building of User Interface

Tags: delphi, user-interface

I am building an user interface. My program will consist of 4 main parts:

1) Top Menu - TMainMenu. A top of a window

2) Main Menu  - TTreeView. A left of a window. Each item of TreeView=corresponded TabSheet of TPageCotrol.

3) Work space - TPageControl. No tabs. An left space.

Each TabSheet has it's own ToolBar and other controls. It will be 5 menus (5 items in TreeView) = 5 TabSheets -> 5 ToolBars and other controls on each TabSheet.

It almost exactly looks like here (it could be: TreeView as Main Menu; MainMenu as Top Menu;  Work Area - ToolBar and other controls):
[image]

I would like to use an user interface like here:
[image]
Where the CoolBar are represented with the Top Menu and the ToolBar (it suits my purpose to use 5 ToolBars instead of 1 ToolBar on each TabSheet). But after a discussion here it seems impossible to copy this CoolBar with the MainMenu and the ToolBar.

My question: how to build an efficient user interface using as examples the UI of uTorrent and the UI of Windows Firewall?

Are there good alternatives, ideas of a building of the UI? How would you make your interface if you need those 4 parts as me?

Now I have something like this:
[image]

Thanks!

Comment: Who voted to close: it is interesting how can I be more specific in this case if I explained my goal and I need suggestions about what controls to use to build the best UI. + I added pictures, they say what I want.

Comment: μTorrent's UI is awful and waay **not** efficient. MMC's and its snap-ins' UI has been constrained by architecture. No, its not clear what you are asking here.

Comment: The pie-chart looks nice! What product is the pie-chart?

Comment: @Downvoter step into the light, pleas tell an example of a program with an efficient UI.

Comment: @maxfax, and the program must be doing *what*? You didnt tell us yet.

Comment: @Downvoter step into the light, nothing special. There is a TreeView, a Label, a ProgressBar, a Panel and a ToolBar with control ToolButtons on the first TabSheet. On second - a PageControl as a WebBrowser. On third - a TreeView, a ListView, a ProgressBar and again a ToolBar. Other TabSheets are like those I have described and each TabSheet has it's own ToolBar. It looks like in Auslogics Disc Explorer (the last pictures). May be I can use another UI instead of mine, that is more efficient than uTorrent's and Auslogics'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to have 5 panels in your client area.

As you select a node in the treeview on the left you will need to call

```
pnlInboundRules.BringToFront;
```

The difficult thing is then how to update the single *toolbar* with the items that should appear on it based on what "*tab*" you've selected.

You would have to delete the toolbar buttons, and add new buttons for that "page".

Comment: _The difficult thing is then how to update the single toolbar with the items that should appear on it based on what "tab" you've selected._ Wouldn't it be as easy as seting action's `Visible` property to FALSE? Ie assign actions to toolbuttons and then set their visible state according to the active tab.

Comment: @ain: I was thinking about using actions like that too, and it would be great if that was enough. But there might also be such fine details as toolbar button separators that would need to be hidden/shown as well.

Comment: @ain: You also then have to have all possible buttons on the toolbar at design time; making it somewhat unwieldy. It might be easier to actually have five *toolbars*, and hide the ones you're not using.

Answer (score 0):

Ian suggest panels, I would go with PageControl and set it's tabs TabVisible to false at runtime(*). The reason is that it is much more easy to manage at design time. When user select an item from treeview, activate corresponding TabSheet...

*) I actually haven't done this with stock TPageControl so I don't rememeber would it work this way, ie would it activate TabSheet which have it's TabVisible set to false. It might be that you have to set TabHeight to 0 or use some other trick to hide tabs at runtime.

Comment: only one tab sheet can be visible at one time this method is fine. It makes no odds whether tabs are visible or not in that regard.

Comment: You just have to jump through hoops (if it's even possible) to hide the tabs, and the raised bevel around the entire `TPageControl`. That's why i use panels.

Comment: I already use the Page Control. It is not a question. The question is how to efficiently use 5 Tool Bars (now each one is on it's own Tab Sheet); the most efficient and elegant way to use TMainMenu and TTreeView as menus.